# Why data of the Vue instance is not updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue 2.2.6 version is used.
I have built very simple Vue instance and I want it to return the list of employees names. But the problem is that after getting `/employees.json` `employees` data is not being updated. I tried to debug it with console.log and it shows that inside `loadData()` function employees data is set correctly. But after this function is executed employees value becomes empty again.

```
var employees = new Vue({
  el: 'employees',
  template: "<ul id='employees'><li v-for='employee in employees'>{{ employee['name'] }}</li></ul>",
  data: {
    employees: []
  },
  methods: {
    loadData: function () {
      this.$http.get('/employees.json').then(response => {
        this.employees = response.body;
       //1. console.log returns here ">employees: [object Object]"
      });
    }
  },
  mounted: function (){
    this.loadData();
    //2. console.log returns here empty employees value
  }
})
```

Where am I wrong? How correctly assign value from `/employees.json` to `employees` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `console.log` in `mounted` will return empty because the `loadData` is asynchronous, and will not have completed.

Your `el` isn't going to work because it needs a #: `'#employees'`
The `template` isn't going to work inline like that, because templates are for components. Where would it put it?

```js
var employees = new Vue({
  el: '#employees',
  data: {
    employees: []
  },
  methods: {
    loadData: function () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('setting');
        this.employees = [{name:'one'},{name:'two'}];
      }, 800);
      /*this.$http.get('/employees.json').then(response => {
        this.employees = response.body;
       //1. console.log returns here ">employees: [object Object]"
      });*/
    }
  },
  mounted: function (){
    this.loadData();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id='employees'><li v-for='employee in employees'>{{ employee['name'] }}</li></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I moved template to component and now it works correctly.